Is it true that for any real valued function $f(t)$ on $\mathbb{R},$ $f(t)a + (1-f(t))b$ is also a line contained in $L$?
I have the following doubt.
We know that for any two points $a$ and $b,$ $L=ta+(1-t)b$ represents a line joining $a$ and $b.$ Is it true that for any real valued function $f(t)$ on $\mathbb{R},$ $f(t)a + (1-f(t))b$ is also a line contained in $L$? I think the answer is yes.

Surely not. The parameter $t$ in the definition of $L$ has a range $[0; 1]$. Any real-valued function won’t have such a property.

In the following, we assume $A \ne B$.
Denote $S = \{f (t) A + (1 - f (t)) B | t \in \mathbb{R}\}$. I claim that $S$ is a subset of the line $L = \{t A + (1 - t) B | t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ joining $A$ and $B$. (When I say "line", I mean line in the geometric sense, not "segment".)
To see this, take an arbitrary point $z \in S$. Then by definition, there exists some $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $z = f (t) A + (1 - f (t)) B$. Denote $s = f (t) \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $z = s A + (1 - s) B$ shows that $z \in L$, as desired.
However, unless $f$ is surjective, $S \subset L$ (strictly). If $f$ is not surjective, then there exists some $s \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f (t) \ne s$ for each $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then it is easy to see that the point $s A + (1 - s) B \in L - S$.
EDIT: Further details.
Of course, $S$ need not be a line. Take for example the constant function $f (x) = 1$. You can check that $S$ contains just a single point: $S = \{A\}$.

Let a line $\mathcal{L}$ join $a$ and $b$. We know that $L(t)=at+b(1-t)$ is a bijection $L:\mathbb{R}\to \mathcal{L}$ if $a\ne b$.
Given a  function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, you are interested in the image of $f(t)a+(1-f(t)b=L\circ f$.
This function is a map $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\to\mathcal{L}$. Given any choice of function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathcal{L}$ we can find functions $f$ such that $\mathcal{L}\circ f=g$.
This means that your expression $f(t)a+(1-f(t)b$ can land on any subset of the line $\mathcal{L}$.
